# Android- how to send a notification to the PC Server using TCP Socket?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am facing an issue and tried my hands on it but not getting it...

I am using TCP socket connection and able to exchange data also but what I need to do is when I receive any message on my android phone, it should automatically be send to a PC server using the socket only when Server is in Listening mode...

Using a Broadcast Receiver, I am able to get the Sms body and sender number and show it on a Toast, but how do I pass the  this String to the server as soon as message arrives on phone without using any send button to send to the server? I am using Wi-fi for creating socket connection.

Comment: If you have tried, share the part of code you are facing problems with

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Android "Service"...
put your code that sends the message to server inside the "onCreate()" method.

Maybe it will work because services run in the background.

I think you are using Android BroadcastReceiver's method onReceive().

Comment: yeah.....Service will also work..but actually m already using an async class n performing my action in background..... so no point using service:(